# Java KeyListener in Ubuntu VM firing all Events at ones

Tags: java, ubuntu, keylistener, awr

I got a problem with my java program, working in a ubuntu virtual machine, using vmware fusion on macosx mountain lion. in my java program i implemented a keylistener, for control a car with W A S D by remote.

The problem with it is, that it fires all events by just pressing the key down and not releasing it.So when i press down a key, it goes:

pressed
typed
released

I noticed that it is a problem inside a virtual machine. Running the program native, it works perfect. So how to solve this? Thanks a lot!